Where can I take an offline or online course to repair and maintain bicycles in India?
I am from Hyderabad, India, and I would like to know where I can get an offline or online course to learn how to repair bicycles. I use cycles from Decathlon.

Do you just want to be able to repair your bicycle at home or do you want to become a professional bicycle mechanic? You will probably find formal courses mainly for the latter. There are many instructional bike repair videos for home repairs from Parktool or GCN and others, it is enough to search for the specific problem.

Local clubs/groups often have courses in basic maintenance.  I've seen them advertised on the facebook group for cyclists in my city, for example

FYI - Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome.

Is there a specific problem you're having with a bike ?

Search for "Online bicycle mechanic training", add "free" if that is important.  Here is the best :)  for specific problems, as is Parktool repair help.

If you have specific problems, then try asking a question here.   Post clear photos, and describe both the problem and what you've tried.
